# Setting the size of the plotting area

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, figure

Let's take a simple example:

```
import plotly.express as px
x = ['A', 'B']
y = [10, 20]
fig = px.bar(x=x, y=y, color=x)
fig.update_layout(autosize=False, width=300, height=300, showlegend=True)
fig.show()
```

[image: result]
I set the width ad height to the same value, but get something rather different. I understand this is because of the space taken by the axes ticks and labels and the legend. So how do I set the size of the plotting area? Say I want a square plot. What should I do?
I tried adding:

```
fig.update_yaxes(
    scaleanchor = "x",
    scaleratio = 1,
)
```

but this didn't change the result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

An option is to place legend such that it is in the plot area

```
import plotly.express as px
x = ['A', 'B']
y = [10, 20]
fig = px.bar(x=x, y=y, color=x)
fig.update_layout(autosize=False, width=200, height=200, showlegend=True, margin={"l":0,"r":0,"t":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(
    yanchor="top",
    y=0.99,
    xanchor="left",
    x=0.01
))
fig.show()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want the legend in the plotting area... also, the axis labels still affect the plot area size. So I'll wait for a better answer, if one exists.